# How to display picture as a header in google-calendar meeting

Tags: google-calendar-api

at the moment My google meetings look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqLr.png)

As u see I have Start timer button, which is created by my chrome extension. But some users have bug with no displaying it when their meeting looks as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Nu0.png)

Thats why I'm tring to get the same view. I tryed to add pictures when editing meeting, but they placed in body of block.

Thanks in forward!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Google Calendar events with certin key names (like `Lunch`, `Coffee` etc.) are created automatically with [background illustration images](https://support.google.com/calendar/forum/AAAAd3GaXpEzYeLzzf9vPg/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fcalendar%2FzYeLzzf9vPg).
- This is different from images added as an attachment to the event.
- Unfortunately, you cannot create your own illustration images - neither through programming nor through the Calendar UI.